# WorkManager - running periodic task

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I'd like to run a periodic task every 3 hours using the new WorkManager.
The worker initiated when the app is created.
I'm using the following code for that:

```
public class ApplicationCommon extends MultiDexApplication {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


    ... some init code
    // some code that I don't want to run again for every periodic worker...
    ... some analytics 
}
```

Inside MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    runCouponValidatorWorker()
}

fun runCouponValidatorWorker() {
    val constraints = Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build()
    val worker = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<CouponValidatorWorker>(3, TimeUnit.HOURS).setConstraints(constraints).build()
    WorkManager.getInstance()?.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("couponValidatorWorker", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, worker)
}
```

However, it seems like the worker, when runs periodically, create a new instance of the Application class every time, and therefore, leads a lot of init code to run again, as if the app were running again by the user (which causes false-positive analytics, API calls etc.). Is there any way to avoid that / have a flag that indicates the app was initiated by the worker?

Comment: Which WorkManager version are you using? And why you written WorkManager code in Application class instead of Activity?

Comment: 1.0.0-alpha04.
And you'ree right (updated question), it should be in an activity class. Anyway, is there any way to know whether the app initiated once again because of a worker?

Comment: Is written somewhere in documentation that it should be initialized in an Activity? I can't find anythink instead of [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/#0) codelab where it is initialized in a ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [PeriodicWorkRequest GitHub demo](https://github.com/patelviraj/WorkManagerDayCounter) and update TimeUnit as per your requirement (i.e. 3-hour) in DayIncrementViewModel.java. It will work as per your need.

To check whether your work is initiated or not you can store UUID in session when you schedule work request. If UUID is null or blank then your WorkRequest is not initiated.
You can also check Work Status using that UUID. Check [this link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) for more detail.

The Demo is in Java but you can convert your code in Kotlin.

**FYI:** **WorkManager 1.0.0-alpha05 is release now** so you should update the WorkManager version because some issues related to PeriodicWorkRequest are fixed in it.